# What are the fundamental differences between Android Room and Sqldelight?

Tags: android, android-room, android-paging, sqldelight

Ignoring multiplatform advantages, is there any advantage of using room over sqldelight?

Answer (score 0):

### [EDITED on 2021/04/25]

SQLDelight now officially supports AndroidX Paging3 as its extension so you may want to check it out:
https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight/releases/tag/1.5.0

---

By using room, you have an official support of paging3 as both libraries are maintained by Google, while sqldelight currently do not support paging3 by itself, so maybe that could be an advantage I guess.

I have not tried yet, but you may be able to use paging3 with sqldelight by creating PagingSource(in Paging3) by your own.

Paging Library Docs:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging#support-different-data-arch

SqlDelight issue about Paging3 support:
https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight/issues/1786